# Как правильно использовать ООП подход в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Последнее время начал использовать классы в JavaScript. В первую очередь, потому что это удобно, код более структурирован.

Методы как правило делал статическими, для того, что бы их можно было вызвать на конкретном элементе. Например:

```
class Catalog {
    static addToCart() {
    // код
    }
}

<button onclick="Catalog.addToCart()">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

И меня это устраивало, пока не наткнулся на статью, что `static` не поддерживается в Safari.

Выходит, мне нужно теперь не использовать статические методы и при вызове создавать экземпляр класса:

```
class Catalog {
    addToCart() {
    // код
    }
}

<button onclick="const catalog = new Catalog(); catalog.addToCart()">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Но мне такой код не очень нравится. Можно ли как то по другому эго писать? Поделитесь своими практиками.

Comment: А вообще хоть кому-то нужен этот сафари?

Comment: вы можете использовать webpack, а именно -> babel

Comment: 'Но мне такой код не очень нравится.' — правильно не нравится) Перед использованием классов хорошо бы перестать смешивать HTML и JS (см. `addEventListener`). Использование классов конкретно в этом примере - тоже сомнительная вещь. Ведь можно создать обычный объект `const catalog = { addToCart() { /*...*/ }, };` и использовать так же. А по поддержке браузеров, можно писать код в удобной для себя форме, а для публикации использовать https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME напрасно вы так, писать смешанный код HTML+inline-JS - это наглядно, логично, и все фичи на своих местах. В ECMAScript7 их вообще объединили в один JSX.

Comment: @DiD я согласен с вами, поэтому так и пишу. OPTIMUSPRIME вам спасибо за комментарии, посмотрю и в эту сторону. по поводу создания констант - я так и делал раньше, но подумал, что так не верно, ведь есть классы. если я буду использовать константы - это не будет ошибкой?

Comment: мне кажется, в вашей задаче вообще не нужны классы/объекты. Подумайте как записать короче. Тут речь о 3-4 функциях. Не надо усложнять.

Comment: А так, да! `var catalog = { addToCart: function(goodId,amount) { /*...*/ }, dropFromCart: function(goodId,amount) { /*...*/ }  };`  будет работать даже в IE6.